# Regex to return only tags with pipe character

Tags: php, regex

I am struggling to get a Regex working.

I have some bad XML that I am having to do some pre-processing on as some of the tags contain one or more pipe characters in them. I am looking to strip them out before I can pass it onto simplexml_load_string() to parse.

a chunk of the XML looks like this:

```
<ALERTNOTEACTIONS>0</ALERTNOTEACTIONS>
<ALLOW|DELIVERY|EDIT>1</ALLOW|DELIVERY|EDIT>
<ALLOW|OVERBOOKING>1</ALLOW|OVERBOOKING>
<ALLOWCASHMOVEMENTSWHENCLOSED>1</ALLOWCASHMOVEMENTSWHENCLOSED>
```

I need to strip the "|" pipe characters out of the tags but leave any pipe characters in the inner content alone.

What I need is the inverse of `/<([\/A-Z|]+)>/i` to only return tags containing pipes, I then use preg_replace to replace the tags. Having spent a few hours trawling through regex examples I can't see how to just require all tags with one or more pipe characters or am I missing something really simple?

Any nicer alternatives offered would also be appreciated.

Comment: Just look for the pipe character anywhere inside angle brackets? `/^<.*\|.*>.*$/`

Comment: What do you plan on replacing these tags with? Do you need to select `<ALLOW|DELIVERY|EDIT>`, or select it and grab `ALLOW` along the way, or...

Comment: @CD001: try it on `<allow>hi|bye</allow>` :/

Comment: @Robin ... aaah gotcha, just realised the mistake as the last `>` will match the last `>` on the closing tag.. yeah, oops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to replace the tags with? Aren't the usual PHP's XML manipulation tools (eg http://www.php.net/manual/fr/refs.xml.php), which are generally recommended for the job, working on your bad XML?

---

As a (quite limited) regex solution, to match tags with a pipe depending on your input something simple could do the trick:

```
<[^><|]*+\|[^><]*+>
```

`[^><]`meaning anything but a `>` or a `<`, it prevents the regex from going ouside of the actual tag.

Using `*+`, a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), will allow the regex to fail and move on more quickly.

This breaks if you have stuff like `<foo|bar bar="1>3" >` (as it would match `<foo|bar bar="1>`) or `<foo|bar bar="1<3" >` (wouldn't match), but could be enough if you don't see these cases (as in your example, see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/pO9lE2)).

Comment: Could extend to `<\/?[^>]*\|[^>]*>` for start and end tags. Also, only the latter example would be broken, not the former.

Comment: @tenub: What would adding `\/` change? `/` is already included in `[^><]`. I edited the regex to solve the first example, so thanks for that :)

Comment: @Robin: Thanks this worked. I needed to iterate `while(preg_match('/<([^><|]*+)\|([^><]*+)>/i', $txt) === 1)` to replace multiple pipes in a tag but it works a treat.

Comment: @MattRink: That's why I was asking what your wanted to do with the pipes or the tags... To replace them all in one go you should then consider Casimir's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to do with pipes inside tags, but if your goal is to remove them from the "tag names", you can use this:

```
$xml = preg_replace('~(?:<|(?!\A)\G)[^>|\s]*+\K\|~', '', $xml);
```

I assume that a pipe inside an attribute (`<AAA attr="|||">`) is not a problem, this is why `\s` is excluded from the character class.

Comment: I don't know if that's an issue for the OP, but just FYI in `<code> 1<3||1==1 </code>` the pipes `|` in the inner-text are selected by your regex

Comment: @Robin: in XML a literal `<` in a text node is not allowed and must be written with an entity `&lt;`. However, you can put one inside comments `<!-- -->` or cdata. But the HTML tag `<code>` is specific  to HTML and has no special behavior in XML. Comments and cdata can be easily avoided begining the pattern with: `(?s:<!--.*?-->|<!\[CDATA\[.*?]]>)(*SKIP)(?!)|`

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, thanks for the regex and explanation !